# Devolver el último argumento de una función

Tags: php, funciones

Les pido ayuda ya que estoy practicando con php y me surgió una duda la cual no he podido responder.

La pregunta es:
**¿cómo puedo devolver el ultimo argumento dado a una función?**

Me refiero a cuando una función recibe parametros "ilimitados". Por ejemplo:

```
function nombre()
{
    for($i = 0; $i < func_num_args(); $i++)
    {
        echo "Saludo para ". func_get_arg($i) .'<br>';
    }
}

nombre("Luis", "Juan", "David");
```

Me refiero en este caso a: **¿cómo podría devolver el valor "David"?**

Esto es lo que he intentado, pero no ha funcionado:

```
function nombre()
{
    for($i = 0; $i < func_num_args(); $i++)
    {
        if($i == func_num_args())
        {
            echo "El ultimo parametros es: " . func_get_arg($i);
        }   
    }
}

nombre("Luis", "Juan", "David");
```

¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

Desde ya, gracias :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para mostrar el último parámetro proporcionado a una función basta con obtener el parámetro `n - 1`, ya que están numerados del `0` (primero) a `n - 1` (último) en vez de `1` a `n` (como estás asumiendo en tu código):

```
function nombre()
{
    echo "El último parámetro es ", func_get_arg(func_num_args() - 1), '<br>', PHP_EOL;
}

nombre("Luis", "Juan", "David");
```

Puedes ver el funcionamiento en línea en el siguiente enlace:

- http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c1309f27da33137786e62efafa257220c353da41

---

También podrías hacer uso de [`func_get_args()`](https://www.php.net/es/func-get-args) para obtener una matriz con todos los parámetros y [`end()`](https://www.php.net/es/end) para quedarte con el último:

```
<?php
function nombre()
{
    $argumentos = func_get_args();
    echo "El último parámetro es ", end($argumentos), '<br>', PHP_EOL;
}

nombre("Luis", "Juan", "David");
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en el siguiente enlace:

- http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8aa866f04a03fe82eacec027c45ecbf91d90bd7d

NOTA: No puedes hacer uso directo de `end(func_get_args())` porque `end()` requiere que el parámetro sea pasado por referencia: `end(array &$array): mixed`.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Si lo que OP necesita es solamente obtener el último elemento, como parece ser, el `for` no tiene ningún sentido.

Comment: @A.Cedano es que lo que intento hacer es ver todos los parametros y hacer algo especial con el último parametro, pero la respuesta de OscarGarcia me ayudó

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía perfecto entonces. Mi comentario se debió a que no hacías nada más con los datos, en cuyo caso recorrerlos todos sería innecesario. Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto, las respuestas de Oscar son siempre de mucha calidad.

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = array( 'Madrid', 'París', 'Londres' );
```

> Imprime "Londres"

```
echo end( $var );
```